# Python Hermite Interpolation (not cubic spline interpolation)

Tags: python, interpolation, hermite

I'm trying to implement various interpolation methods in python without using fancy libraries, such as scipy or numpy. I've managed to implement Lagrange interpolation both using Lagrange polynomial and Newton's polynomial. Now, I'm trying to implement Hermite interpolation, however, all resources no matter how I search take me to cubic spline interpolation, instead of a single hermite polynomial. Could someone provide me with a working solution for Hermite interpolation in any programming language, even with only first derivative, so that I can get familliar with the code and understand it, to be able to implement it myself in Python?

Comment: Start with [link](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). This will help you to ask the question in the way we can help you.  What have you already done? Where is the difference between expected result and the real result you have.